# MongoDB Python: Unable to remove a field that has a . in it

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm using pymongo and I'm unable to remove a field that has a "." in the field name. I've tested this same code with other fields that do not have a period and it works without an issue.

```
db.city.update_many({}, {'$unset': {'AverageDailyPM2.5':1}})
```

I'm pretty certain I'm on the latest versions of everything including MongoDB 4.4.9.

Answer (score 0):

That is one of the reasons it is not recommended to use "." in a field name.

If you use the pipeline form of update, you can convert the object to an array with `$objectToArray` so the fields become data, remove the desired field from the array with `$filter`, convert back to an object with `$arrayToObject`, and then use `$replaceRoot` to make that the final document.